# How to Skip and return in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How to skip over a line when writing a csv file after it has been read. I am wanting to skip the line that has the word "DISAPPROVE" in the 54th comma section. I am having to read it in from one location and then have to take all that was read and write it into a new location. It seems the easiest way to skip over a line that has "DISAPPROVED" in the 54th comma space is to skip over it when writing the CSV file. Where and what do I have to add to make this happen though??

```
'Reads The original file
Reader = New StreamReader("R:\FilePath.csv")
Dim stAll As String = reader.ReadToEnd
reader.Close()

'Writes the new file
MonitorIDTextFile = New StreamWriter("R:\NewFilePath.csv)
MonitorIDTextFile.WriteLine(stALL)
MonitorIDTextFile.Close()
```

Comment: _ANY_ column in the file, or a specific column in the file?

Comment: It's a specific column in the file. I am currently using a for loop where I = 0- count of rows  then (I, 64)  populates all my disapprove or approved values

Answer (score 1):

If *any* column could contain the "DISAPPROVED" text:

```
Dim lines = Get2dArrayFromCSV().
      Where(Function(line) line.Any(Function(cell) Not cell.Equals("DISAPPROVED")) ).
      ToArray()
```

If you only need to look in a specific column:

```
' Assuming column index is "3". Adjust accordingly
Dim lines = Get2dArrayFromCSV().
      Where(Function(line) Not line[3].Equals("DISAPPROVED")).
      ToArray()
```

Personally, I'd also remove the `ToArray()` and keep the basic `IEnumerable` interface for as long as possible.

Now you can work the lines array however you need, such as with a `For Each` loop.

Comment: I thought about this for a while now and thought of this new idea I changed my question and added some of my current code any thoughts? I thought this may be the fastest easiest way.

Comment: @NathanielTurner It will definitely be less efficient to load an entire large set into RAM before writing it back out. If that's the process, .Net makes it easy to build this so it only ever has one line of the file in RAM at a time. It's also less efficient to repeatedly read/write the same data to and from disk multiple times if it is known to be small enough to fit in memory.